# Ballistic Conduction - Difference between Bosonic and Fermionic Transport

Tags: electrons, nanoscience, phonons

[Ballistic Conduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballistic_conduction) is the phenomenon of an ideal conduction environment for quantum particles - for electrons the Ballistic Conduction is not infinity, but is proportional to the difference between Fermi surfaces of the leads on both sides.
One of the reasons, it seems to me, is that electron is a Fermion and cannot occupy the "transport state" that spans the length of the leads - if there is another electron occupying it. [Supriyo Dutta](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521599431) also argues for this in terms of chemical potential.
It seems to me then that for bosons like phonons or photons, if there exists even one state spanning the leads, there should be an effective short circuit and the transmission would be the theoretical maximum. Is that true?